# Arms Workout per Week

Tags: diet, body-fat, upper-body-workout, body-measurements, arms

I doing gym for almost 5 months.I got nice shoulders and chest.But when it come to arms i feel something left out.I was thinking of doing arms 2-3 times a week.Is it good to do that and if i do that how i'm gonna cover my other body parts.

I have chest of 38-40 inches and i got arms of 12 inches only. I like to go for 14-16 because my height is 5'11 and its feel like an average arms.
Please help me
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Large muscle groups develop in a more obvious way than the smaller ones. That said, you clearly understand how to build muscle through effective diet and exercise.

Arms can be trained through a number of means, there are 3 major muscle groups. I'll list the best exercises that have their major focus on that muscle group but are the best compound version:

## Biceps

- **Barbell Bicep Curl**: This is the simplest and when done standing engages your core and posterior chain to keep you upright. Play around with grip, some people struggle with standard grip. Overhand also works forearms as well.
- **Dumbbell Bicep Curl**: Do this standing for the reasons above. Also start the exercise with your weakest arm to ensure that you don't over-work one side.
- **Cable Curl**: Same as above but you get linear resistance throughout the movement.
- **Other:** Chin-ups, any rowing movement, any variation on above (preacher, seated)

## [Triceps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwAD78Z_1ck)

- Dips: And their best friend, weighted dips. Also builds chest. Seriously, everyone should be doing 3x10 dips.
- Close Grip Bench Press: Bench. Press. Don't let elbows flare out.
- Cable Tricep Pushdown: As with biceps, gives resistance across whole ROM.
- Other: Skull crushers, Diamond push ups, Behind the neck plate raises

## [Forearms](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avjzXagXYGY)

- Deadlifts: Just lots of really heavy deadlifts with a normal, double overhand grip.
- Farmers Walks: Pick up 2 32-50KG kettlebells or dumbbells and go for a walk.
- Hold something heavy.
- Hang from something.

Comment: Thanks for listing those exercise I Try to work on that @JJosaur

Comment: But I want to know how many times should i work on those muscles @jjosaur

Comment: Depends on your overall routine, personally I would do 3-4 sets of 10-15 reps at 60-80% of my training max, on a PushPullLegs split you would do triceps during push day, biceps on pull day and forearms on leg day but you could work out all 3 together if you are only doing 3 times a week.

Answer (score 3):

> “I was thinking of doing arms 2-3 times a week.Is it good to do that
>   and if i do that how i'm gonna cover my other body parts.”

If your goal is a balanced, aesthetic physique, then, “more is **not** necessarily better”.  Hypertrophy is a very **individual** thing.  There’s **no** specific set of exercises that will guarantee you growth for a specific muscle group.  While exercise selection does contribute to muscle growth, I think it’s much more important to examine your approach to training.  Ask yourself, “*Is my training approach optimum for making muscular gains?*”.

You need to understand that you build muscular size when you optimize your nutrition, sleep, and recovery.  If one facet of your training is “off”, chances are, you will not make gains.  Closely examining each of these should provide insight into any potential areas that are lacking.

If you feel that you’re training optimally, there is one change that may be effective for you. If you feel that a particular body part is lagging, you should take a look at prioritizing your routine.  An excerpt from the [National Strength and Conditioning Association](http://www.humankinetics.com/products/all-products/NSCAs-Guide-to-Program-Design) indicates that

> “The order of exercises within a workout significantly affects acute
>   lifting performance and subsequent changes in strength during
>   resistance training. The primary training goals should dictate the
>   exercise order. Exercises performed early in the workout are completed
>   with less fatigue, yielding greater rates of force development, higher
>   repetition number, and greater amount of weights lifted.”

If you feel that your arms are lacking, you should consider training biceps and triceps earlier in your routine.  You should also consider using “pre-exhaustion” as a method to stimulate growth.

Lastly, achieving muscle growth, for those training drug-free, should be considered as a long term goal.  If you **consistently** optimize your training, the cumulative effect should be obvious in later years.

Answer (score 0):

These are principles given by Arnold

1. Basically it you should consider training weak parts on high priority.
   You can train then multiple times
2. You can train arms twice a week but you will need to make sure that hypertrophy is attained
3. You need to give sufficient rest to your muscles to recover, biceps require min 24hrs for recovery, and it varies from person to person
4. You need to take proper nutrition (I assume it is in place )
   Taking care of all these things will lead you to results with bigger and stronger muscles

I too had biceps of 12.5-13inches,  but now they are 15inches